# Confluent Kafka - Control Center did not get installed, doesn't start up

Tags: macos, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I'm following Confluent Kafka QuickStart guid here "https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/quickstart/ce-quickstart.html#ce-quickstart".
The page offers this command to startup everything at once like this:
`confluent local services start`

Then it shows a short list in command line what starts up. The list ends with the following:
`Starting Control Center`
`Control Center is [UP]`

When I run the command, I don't see the Control Center. Then when I'm trying to view the basic page "http://localhost:9021/", it shows this error - ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

It looks like the install command is not installing the Control Center. I've ran the install command twice. I'm missing control-center.properties file, and I'm missing the folder confluent-control-center that suppose to be in the etc folder.

I'm using Mac, my installation is on the Mac. Would appreciate any help getting this running properly.

Comment: Are you using same machine to issue the service start and running the browser to localhost?

Comment: @RanLupovich Yes, same machine, Mac. And I do see Zookeeper and Kafka starting up, but not the Control Panel.

Comment: @RanLupovich it appears I'm missing control-center.properties file.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting rid of the download, then re-downloaded the Confluent Platform as a zip file. I don't remember if it was a tar file earlier. The new download has the Control Center folders and files.